# NServiceBus: Cache subscriber list?

Tags: nservicebus

For my usage of NServiceBus, I really do not need to get an updated list of subscribers once for each publish. I only need to get it one time at startup, so as to avoid the wasted time on querying this over and over again.

I found discussion about caching the subscriber list  - [here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1320), but in the end it does not provide a solution.  Can anyone provide a concrete solution?  I am using NSB 4.6.4.

Comment: What storage are you using?

Comment: either RavenDB or SqlServer with NHibernate, whichever can provide better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are seeing an actual performance problem with fetching subscribers, I would see this as premature optimization.  If you are using Raven, the database fetch should be very, very fast.

It sounds like they will implement caching in NHibernate in 5.0, so you may have to wait for that if you are using SQL.  I'm not sure how subscription data is stored in SQL, so I can't comment on how fast/slow it is currently.